# Inserting data into a mysql database using perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I don't code in mysql or perl and I am writing a program which parses and xml file and inserts the data into a mysql database in C++. I found a script to do this that I call from my C++ code but get this error:

> Unknown column 'subject' in 'field list' at ./xml_to_mysql.pl line 107

And here is the code for the script which does the inserting:

```
#@_IMPORT_DOCUMENT_
# Open file for reading

my $xp = XML::XPath->new (filename => $file_name);
my $row_list = $xp->find ("//row");

print "Number of records: " . $row_list->size () . "\n";
foreach my $row ($row_list->get_nodelist ())
{
     my @name; #array of column names
     my @val; #array of column names
     my $col_list = $row->find ("*");
     foreach my $col ($col_list->get_nodelist ())
     {
         push (@name, $col->getName ());
         push (@val, $col->string_value ());
     }
     #construct INSERT statement, then execute it 
     my $stmt = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name ("
                . join (",", @name)
                . ") VALUES ("
                . join (",", ("?") x scalar (@val))
                . ")";
     $dbh->do ($stmt, undef, @val);
}
```

**Line 107 is the line which contains the line:**

```
$dbh->do ($stmt, undef, @val);
```

Comment: I cannot find any C++ code in this question.

Comment: I only run this script in the C++ code. The error is from the script

Comment: If the problem is not in the C++ code and the C++ code is not needed to show us the problem, I see no reason for the C++ tag. Please remove it if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Does your table have the column `subject`? Are you inserting data in the right table?

Answer (score 2):

The error seems pretty clear to me. You are generating an SQL INSERT statement which tries to insert data into a column called 'subject'. But the table you are inserting data into doesn't have a column called 'subject'.

Given that you're generating your SQL from an XML document, the solution will be one of these two options:

1. Add a 'subject' column to the table
2. Skip processing the XML element that adds this data to the SQL

Which of them you choose depends entirely on how your program is supposed to work. We can't be any help there.

Comment: Realised the error was in the table. Can anyone please help me with a way to get a 'create table' statement from an unknown xml file.Any help will be appreciated